Smallest natural number unrepresentable by fifty letters
What is the problem of the proof of this claim? I also think it is really strange, but I can't find the problem.
Claim:
All natural numbers can be uniquely represented using fifty letters.
Proof:
Assume that claim is wrong. Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ which contains all natural numbers that can not be uniquely represented using fifty letters. Because of well-ordering principle, there exists $\operatorname{min} (X)$, which is unique and can be represented by 'smallest natural number unrepresentable by fifty letters', which is exactly $50$ letters. This is a contradiction. The claim is then true.
I really want to know the problem of this proof.
Is the term 'uniquely representable by $50$ letters' not precise?

Did I miscount or that phrase is just $48$ letters?

Sorry, I made a typo. I edited it and it's 50 letters now.

If set $X$ is empty set, doesn't it mean that all natural numbers can be uniquely represented using fifty letters, which is the claim?

This is called Richard's Paradox.  Whoever presented it casually as a proof was being... detrimental, to try to put it nicely.  Most paradoxes of this nature do not have a simple explanation because they are not rigorous enough to be corrected.  With this paradox the main issue lies in the difficulty of the word "represented".  For example, represented can't mean primitive recursive arithmetic, because that wouldn't allow you to encode the original claim.  An actual full explanation is, as far as my opinion, beyond the scope of this question/answer website though.

There are many variants of this paradox , for example the proof that every number is interesting. If this is false  , there must be a smallest uninteresting number , but this property makes the number interesting. Also, I think , the name is "Berry's paradox".

W.V.O. Quine has an essay about this, called "The Ways of Paradox".  I haven't read it in a while, but I think his conclusion is that it shows that our intuitive notion of what it means for a sentence (or a word) to describe something is naïve, and missing something essential.

Let $n$ be the number of letters in the alphabet.  (For this purpose, we may interpret the word “letter” to include mathematical operators and punctuation marks, but assume that there is a finite alphabet of permitted symbols.)  Then there are $n^{50}$ possible 50-letter strings, and thus a maximum of $n^{50}$ representable numbers.  But this is a finite number, whereas $|\mathbb{N}|$ is infinite.  Thus, there must be natural numbers that cannot be represented by 50-letter strings, Q.E.N.D.

So what is the smallest number not representable by 50 letters?

@Peter Ah you are right, the term "Berry's Paradox" is more to the point of this one.

@Peter Surely you mean the least uninteresting number?

English is too expressive a language for that. In particular, it has sentences that can refer to themselves, which generally leads to problems like the Liar's Paradox. For example, "the number which is 1 if this description represents 2, and 2 if this description doesn't represent 2".
Your example hides the self-reference a little bit, but it's there - the set of all descriptions less than fifty letters includes the description 'smallest natural number unrepresentable by fifty letters', so it's depending on itself.
It would work if you used a more restrictive language. For example, "The smallest natural number which cannot be represented in less than fifty symbols, using only the digits $0$ to $9$, the symbols $+, -, ×, ÷, \wedge$, and brackets" is well-defined.

This explanation is missing something essential. The problem is not a property of English, or even of natural language generally.  Saul Kripke observed that this issue arises for a very general class of two-place relations. One of these relations is "$X$ is a description of $Y$", but it also applies in many situations where there is no self-reference to be found.

@MJD Do you have a reference to a (more or less) non referential version of this paradox?  I'd be interested to see it.

Try Kripke's paper "The Road to Gödel" http://saulkripkecenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Road-to-G%C3%B6del-PUBLIC.pdf . Also note in for example that the technique used to construct the Gödel sentence in the first incompleteness theorem does not involve self-reference.

The problem with your proof is that is the "represent" operation is multivalued.
There are phrases that can represent multiple numbers, such as "The most interesting number" and many other opiniated statements. Also the phrase "natural number" can represent an infinity of numbers.
You cannot use a multivalued operation to construct set X in your proof (or at least not a simple set).
Note: If we do assume that one phrase can only "represent" one number, the counter-proof is trivial (there are only so many unique combinations of 50 letters).

To be even more pedantic, the "represent" operation is also non-injective, meaning most (all?) numbers can be represented by more than one phrase.
For example, 7 can be represented as "seven" and also as "six plus one" and "five plus two", etc.
So the "uniquely represented" part of your claim is oximoronic, as most numbers cannot be represented uniquely at all.
In fact, a more interesting problem: can you find the smallest number that can be actually "uniquely represented" using fifty letters? I.e. is there a number (probably very large) that you can only represent with 1 phrase and no other?
